# Implement new payment method in odoo 16

Tags: xml, odoo

Is there a standard view for creating a new payment method? I made my module to implement payments by qr but when I add it, it does not appear in the payment providers menu.

I understand that this is a payment method structure, but it does not recognize it in accounting as a payment method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <record id="payment_provider_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">QR Simple Provider Form</field>
        <field name="model">payment.provider</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="payment.payment_provider_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <group>
            </group>
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```